# Can I use a Honeywell thermocouple in a State water heater?

Tags: water-heater, thermocouple

I have a State water heater that's around 13 years old. About a month ago, the pilot light went out randomly and I was able to relight it with no problems. A couple of days ago, the light went out again but I was not able to ignite it again using the built-in igniter. After some research, it seems like the likely culprit could be the thermocouple. The model number of the heater is GS650UBRT100.

I found the parts catalog and was able to find the original part through Sears PartsDirect (http://www.searspartsdirect.com/part-number/9000056015/0042/153.html). However, if I order it now, it probably won't arrive for another week.

The Home Depot has a generic thermocouple by Honeywell, and I was wondering if I can use that instead: http://www.homedepot.com/p/Honeywell-24-in-Universal-Gas-Thermocouple-CQ100A1013/202216463

The manual refers to my water heater's part as a thermopile, but the parts catalog says it's a thermocouple, so I'm confused as to what it actually is, and if it's interchangeable. Would I be ok with getting the generic thermocouple for my specific water heater? It says it's for 30mV systems, but I can't find the specification for my specific model.

This is the heater's manual: http://www.statewaterheaters.com/lit/im/res-gas/186221-004.pdf
And the parts catalog: http://www.statewaterheaters.com/lit/partslist/res-gas/186298-000.pdf

Also, what are the chances the problem is caused by another part, such as the pilot assembly kit or the igniter? Should I start with replacing the thermocouple and go from there?

On an unrelated note, I've attached a picture of my water heater. I noticed that there's a pipe on the very right with the valve closed. What is this pipe, and why is the valve closed? Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: @isherwood - I meant the other pipe to the very right (coming out of the wall) and attached to the red thing and extends all the way down.

Comment: That pipe is part of a recirculation loop, the red thing is a pump.  If the valves closed its been turned off.  If that system is working it keeps hot water circulating so that when you turn on hot water there is very little wait time for the water to be hot.  The trade-off is more energy is used because the pipes are kept hot all the time.

Comment: Regarding the thermocouple... Is the flame lighting but going out when you release pilot override button?  Or are you getting spark but no flame?  If thats the case it's more a case of the spark not being strong enough, or its moved and is no longer in line of the gas from the pilot nozzel.  The thermocouple is bad when you can light the flame but it goes out when you take your thumb off the pilot override (the button you hold 60 seconds).

Comment: Also my experience has been that if the nut on the valve end if the thermocouple is the correct fitting for the gas valve, then it will be a compatible thermocouple.

Comment: @Tyson the flame doesn't light at all. It's hard to tell from the viewport, but I don't think I'm seeing a spark. What would have caused it to move? The heater is behind a closed door, so it's kind of weird that it would move on its own. Also, would a bad igniter cause the flame to go out in the first place?

Comment: What can move it is expansion and contraction from the burner going on and off for 13 years.   But you don't have a thermocouple problem, you have an ignightor problem.  Or possibly both since the pilots going out.  Tackle the ignightor first tho, if it keeps going out weekly then you also have a thermocouple or week pilot issue.

Comment: Should I reposition or replace it?

Comment: Depends, you need to get it out and look.  Might just be carbon buildup to remove.  Is the ignitor button the spring loaded thunker type that makes one spark per push? Or more of a button thats easier to push and makes a stream of sparks?  That type has an AA battery in the button, I've never seen that type on a hot water heater tho.

Comment: It's the first type. I'll inspect it and post updates. In case I need to replace it, which part is it: http://www.statewaterheaters.com/lit/partslist/res-gas/186298-000.pdf BTW, thanks for the thorough and prompt responses.

Comment: The part you might want to just go get and try first is the ignitor button, those can go bad, at the other end it's just a tip that jumps a spark against the pilot.  The buttons pretty generic, whatever home depot's got with a mounting clip like yours should be good.  It unplugs without you having to disassemble the burner.

Comment: @Tyson - Ok, after checking it again, I can confirm that the igniter is actually working; I do see a spark. It was harder to tell earlier because it was bright outside. Is the thermocouple the likely culprit now?

Comment: The key is flame.  If you get flame and it goes away when you take your finger off the pilot override then you have a thermocouple issue.  Spark and no flame is still the ignitior.

Answer (score 1):

First, I agree with the above comments:  I use a 400 fine-grit sandpaper to clean off the existing thermocouple tip and I clean off the pilot tip as well.

As a separate precaution, I would check the spark on the igniter assembly by disconnecting it then watching for the small blue spark at the hand-button (DUH, only after turning off the gas!)

Yes, you can use the Honeywell 30mV t-couple with the State if/when the threads in the gas control valve seat fit.

Lastly, **note** that some State water heaters have a high-temperature shunt soldered in-line with the thermocouple. These are a retrofit part to repair problems in hot-weather climates (like Arizona and Southern Nevada.)  In that case, the thermocouple with the shunt 'ignores' high ambient temperatures in garages, etc. I have had to replace my State water-heater thermocouple a few  times because the shunt resistor cracks. Of course the cracking problem only occurs in cold, winter temperatures.

[The parts list for your heater is found here](http://www.statewaterheaters.com/lit/partslist/res-gas/186298-000.pdf); and it looks like yours (at least originally) did not have the high-temp shunt resistor version of the thermocouple.  Your thermocouple #9000056015 is manufactured by AO Smith and (for example) [could be purchased here](http://www.supplyhouse.com/AO-Smith-9000056015-Thermocouple-Kit-Model-TC-K24?gclid=CjwKEAiAp97CBRDr2Oyl-faxqRMSJABx4kh9LVY3WcQNdRdtLwwlRnn0TzdkBRtv29smKRfYvj6vcxoChRHw_wcB) or elsewhere.

Bottom line:  go get the Honeywell and a 2nd push-button igniter; order a 2nd AO Smith thermocouple online; clean and test your existing ones if you are up for it....please post back your progress.

Answer (score 0):

Thermocouple's and thermal piles are the same thing in this case (like Ford and Chevy). As long as the base threads into the valve and the tip can be placed in the flame it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Had a state water heater with similar symptoms.  I tried to get new thermocouple from local plumbing supply store.  They quoted me $99!!!  I told them it's around $30 online, they got upset with me.

I noticed that the burner assembly had been jury-rigged and previously someone had put in universal thermocouple from Honeywell (tisistor was cracked but wires were cut and was isolated.

So I put in anotger Honeywell thermocouple, worked okay, few days later, problems.  A plumber friend came by and said it maybe that my vents are clogged.  Vent was fine but the water heater had an internal air filter.  Was clogged with animal hair (maybe prev owner had a cat?).  It's now working fine.